# AWK/SED/getline - How to simplify/improve this example?

Tags: awk, sed, getline

I'm trying to take a 3 column input file and separate it based on a condition in column 3. I think it'll be easier to show you than explain:

Input File:

```
outputfile1.txt
 26         NCC      1     # First Start
 38         NME      2
 44         NSC      1     # Start2
 56         NME      2
 62         NCC      1     # Start3
...
314         NCC      1     # Start17
326         NME      2
332         NSC      1     # Start18
344         NME      2
349         NME      2     # Final End
```

(The hashed comments aren't part of the file, I've added to make things clearer).

*Column 3* is used to determine a new "START" entry

"START/END" values are from *Column 1*

"TITLE" I would like to be all values from *Column 2* between consecutive "STARTS"

**Desired Output**

```
outputfile2.txt
START=26 ; END=43 ; TITLE=NCC_NME
START=44 ; END=61 ; TITLE=NSC_NME
START=62 ; END=79 ; TITLE=NCC_...
...
START=314 ; END=331 ; TITLE=NCC_NME
START=332 ; END=349 ; TITLE=NSC_NME
```

Crude script that 'almost' does this but makes 5 single column temporary files in the process.

```
awk '{ print $1 }' outputfile1.txt | sed '$d' > tempfile1.txt
awk '{ print $1-1 }' outputfile1.txt | sed '$d' > tempfile2.txt
sed '$d' outputfile1.txt | awk 'NR{print $3-p}{p=$3}' > tempfile3.txt

awk '  { getline value < "tempfile1.txt" }
       { if (NR==1)
       print value ;
       else if( $1 != 1 )
       print value }' tempfile3.txt > tempfile4.txt

awk '  { getline value < "tempfile2.txt" }
       { if (NR==1)
       print value ;
       else if ( $1 != 1 )
       print value }' tempfile3.txt | sed '1d' > tempfile5.txt
awk 'END{print $1}' outputfile1.txt >> tempfile5.txt

awk '   { getline value < "tempfile5.txt" }
        {print "START="$0 " ; END="value}' tempfile4.txt > outputfile2.txt
```

**Contents of temp files**

```
       |  temp1     temp2     temp3
NR=1   |  26        25        1
NR=2   |  38        37        1
NR=3   |  44        43        -1
NR=4   |  56        55        1
NR=5   |  62        61        -1
...    |  ...       ...       ...
NR=33  |  314       313       -1
NR=34  |  326       325       1
NR=35  |  332       331       -1
NR=36  |  344       343       1
----------------------------------
       | temp4     temp5
NR=1   |  26        43
NR=2   |  44        61
NR=3   |  62        79
...    |  ...       ...
NR=17  |  314       331
NR=18  |  332       359
```

---

**Current output**

```
outputfile2.txt
START=26 ; END=43
START=44 ; END=61
START=62 ; END=79
...
START=314 ; END=331
START=332 ; END=349
```

Comment: Some tips for future: 1) never use sed for processing multiple input lines at once, use awk instead. 2) You never need sed if you're already using awk. 3) There are only a very few specific types of problem where a solution using getline is appropriate, see http://awk.info/?tip/getline

Comment: its better u post the Question http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Will keep in mind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do everything in one go using:

```
awk '{ 
  if(NR==1){    

     # if we are the first record we initialize our variables
     PREVIOUS_ONE=$1
     TITLE=$2
     PREVIOUS_THIRD=$3

  } else {

    # as long as the new third column is larger we update our variables
    if(PREVIOUS_THIRD < $3) { 

       TITLE=TITLE"_"$2
       PREVIOUS_THIRD=$3

    } else {  
       # this means the third column was smaller
       # we print out the data and reinitialize our variables
       print "START="PREVIOUS_ONE" ; END="$1-1" ; TITLE= "TITLE;

       PREVIOUS_ONE=$1 
       TITLE=$2
       PREVIOUS_THIRD=$3
    }   
  }
  }' outputfile1.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
awk '
  function print_range() {
    printf "START=%s ; END=%s ; TITLE=%s\n", start, end-1, title
  }

  {
    end=$1
  }

  # if column 3 is equal to 1, then there is a new start
  $3==1 {
    if(title) print_range()
    start=$1
    title=$2
    next
  }

  # if the label in field 2 is not part of the title then add it
  title!~"(^|_)" $2 "(_|$)" {
    title=title"_"$2
  }

  END {
    end++
    print_range()
  }
' file
```